# Two Earth-explorers encounter aliens, learn Earth had lost war in past; aliens thought humans were extinct

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Two human explorers land on a planet and encounter an alien. The alien tells them that long ago humans were a cruel and oppressive space-faring species. For example, they genetically engineered one subjugate alien-race to remove a limb. A long war was fought that had been thought to exterminate humans but it seems it failed. The alien kills the humans and examines their space-craft to discover the location of Earth but the data was automatically erased when the humans died.

n.b. The book is **not** "[Protected Species](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68898/sci-fi-short-story-help-surprise-ending-h-beam-piper>)" by H B Fyfe.

Comment: http://hell.pl/szymon/Baen/The%20best%20of%20Jim%20Baens%20Universe/The%20World%20Turned%20Upside%20Down/0743498747__13.htm - *"Somehow they found a way to alter the genes of the Apectans, who were humanoids like themselves, and they did it on a mass scale. They did not choose to exterminate the race, their revenge was much greater. Every Apectan born since the Antha invasion, has been born without one arm."*

Comment: Spot on! Thanks