# Archaeologist on alien planet encounters an alien that tells him the ruins are from a previous human culture

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

I thought I had asked this question before but it's not in my history.

I'm trying to identify a short story, possibly from the 70s or 80s.

A team of archaeologists is exploring ruins on an alien planet and there are reports of 'ghosts' by some of the team to the team-leader. The team-leader eventually encounters the ghost and it turns out to be an alien who informs the leader that the ruins are of a previous human civilisation. That is, "these aren't our ruins, they are yours".

It's possible that I am conflating/confusing it with a completely different story in which two star-faring astronauts encounter an alien and are told that a previous human civilisation had conquered a large part of the galaxy and ultimately been beaten at great expense. "We thought you had all gone". The travel log on the starship automatically erases itself and the peaceful galactic civilisation are left wondering where the hated and feared humans are hiding.

Comment: duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68898/sci-fi-short-story-help-surprise-ending-h-beam-piper?

Comment: @Paul - Protected Species is one. The other is probably [All the way Back](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/52022/20774)

Comment: Agreed, but it's supposed to be one question per thread so I'm responding to the main question :-)

Comment: Thank you everyone, spot on